# Possible to access Sheet/Report Email Object (Smartsheet)

Tags: smartsheet-api

I think I know the answer to this, and will write an enhancement request if I am correct, but ...

Is it possible to access (either just get it or to update it) the Email Object that is a part of a Sheet or Report?
I am referring to the Email Object that is created when Send As Attachment is setup  with Delivery settings that are recurring.

From my investigation of the Python SDK, I have not seen it.

-Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, I don't believe that's a property that's settable or gettable via the API.

An enhancement request would certainly be the way to go here.

Comment: I thought so and have added an enhancement request.